# How could I turn a floppy disk into a smartcard?

Tags: login, floppy, smartcard

I'm a fan of old technology such as the floppy diskette and I would like to find a 21st century use for it.

So my question is; with the smartcard technology we have to day, such as Charismathics and PassagePoint, how could I turn a floppy diskette into a smartcard?

My goal is to have the diskette autorun a logon script without any user intervention other than inserting it into the drive. A cardkey essentially.

Can this be done? I'm hoping to do this in either Windows or Linux.

Comment: A diskette is useless without the drive, and the drive needs to be connected to a controller.  The FDC (floppy disk controller) is getting (or already is) scarce as an integrated peripheral on PCs..

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how a smartcard is related to "autorun a logon script"?

Anyway. Floppy disks *cannot* act as full-featured smartcards. (They don't even have any electronics in them, which a smartcard would need to perform cryptographic ops.) So that could be done if you gutted the disk *and* the drive, and glued an actual smartcard in one, a card reader in the other.

At best, you could use a floppy disk as a sort of simple password-replacement, similar to how https://github.com/aluzzardi/pam_usb works for USB sticks – it would probably work with /dev/fd0 with only minimal adaptation.

The PAM module works by checking that the disk contains a secret file matching some hash, and even has some basic protection against copies/replays by regenerating the secret on every login (since the floppy disk itself is just a 'dumb' storage device & cannot prevent someone from simply copying the "secret" file).